# What is the difference between sekva and sekvanta?

Tags: word-usage

I am looking for the word to use when saying, "the next [thing]".  For example,

"The next meeting..."

"The next year..."

I found the words **sekva** and **sekvanta**. Is one of these the right word to use? For example,

"Mia sekva[nta] projekto estos..."

Are these two words interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider the definitions in PIV (vortaro.net)

***sekva***.

- *Posta, jena, ĉi-suba.*

***sekvanta***

1. Tuj posta: la sekvantan tagon […] ŝi estis jam en la urboZ; dum la tuta sekvanta tago li staris sur unu piedo<sup>Z</sup>; eniri en la sekvantan ĉambron.
2. Jena, troviĝanta en la posta frazo: unu el ĝiaj dogmoj estas la sekvanta<sup>Z</sup>; la diferencon vi komprenos pli bone el la sekvantaj ekzemploj<sup>Z</sup>.

Looking at it this way, you could say they're essentialy synonymous.

Since another answer mentions *venonta* - I will point out that this merely means "coming in the future" *La venonta vendredo* will be understood as the next Friday to come, but "next" is not inherent in *venonta* as it is in *sekva/sekvanta*.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, people say **venonta**, which means "that which will come" or "upcoming".

Mia venonta projekto estos....

Comment: "Normally" in what sense? Can you quantify that somehow? "Sekva" and "sekvanta" are quite normal words.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Just personal experience (anecdotal).

Comment: In that case, I will assert that it's not "normal" here, and this answer doesn't answer the question and could be misleading. *Venonta* can only refer to something in the future and is rarely used to refer to an event in the past (the next project after that was...) In the Tekstaro, variations of "sekvanta tago" are a dozen times more common than "venonta tago."